# Use smartGwt with playframework

Tags: gwt, playframework, smartgwt

Please How can I integrate smartGwt 2.3 with play?, I'm using GWT2 [gwt2] module 1.8, but I don't know how to add smartgwt components

Answer (score 3):

Well it runs with this configuration

```
require:
    - play
    - play -> gwt2 1.8

    - com.google.gwt -> gwt-user 2.3.0
    - com.google.gwt -> gwt-dev 2.3.0    
    - com.smartgwt -> smartgwt 2.5


repositories:
    - smartgwt:
        type: iBiblio
        root: "http://www.smartclient.com/maven2/"
        contains:
            - com.smartgwt -> *
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the way from Raphael Bauer which is described at the [google-group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/3b9848cbff4a9c67/cd6051b73375396b?lnk=gst&q=Berlin#cd6051b73375396b). There Play is a restful-server which delivers JSON-Messages. Then you use GWT with RestyGWT. No need to use a special module. So you can use GWT-Extension as you usual do.

Comment: This is quite incorrect, there is no issue integrating SmartGWT and Play's restful server (or any restful server)

Comment: I trusted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915374/smartgwt-with-gwt. There you need a special client library. So the idea simply use JSON-Message shouldn't work. How ever I'm not a GWT expert, but if it was really false you should add a comment to the other thread too.

Comment: I have already commented on the other thread - the other thread does not say anything about incompatibility with Play - sorry, I don't know why you're confused, but there is no incompatibility issue, so please don't claim that there is the future, thanks.

Comment: I never said that Smart-GWT doesn't work with play. I only assumed that it wouldn't work with RestyGWT because I thought it has it's own service-layer. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, however, this *still* wouldn't pose an incompatibility problem for SmartGWT because you can *both* use whatever custom code you want to fulfill a DataSource request (called a clientCustom DataSource and is how some people interact with GWT-RPC services) *and* you could also just populate components such as a ListGrid directly, without using a DataSource.  So your answer is still wrong and it would be good to correct it.

Comment: I can't see what there could be wrong. I recommend to use not the play-module, that's all. Furthermore I link to another article where someone says you can't easily only parts from SmartGWT. In the update I clarify that this information could be wrong. So at last there is no statement if it works or not. So nothing could be wrong.

Comment: It still says "However smartGWT will not work with it".  This is incorrect.  Also, in the other article, the person who says you can't easily use just parts of SmartGWT was also incorrect.  Furthermore, even if SmartGWT could not be used partially, it still would not be a problem for integration with Play.  So if you could correct your answer that would be great.

Comment: Sorry I have two statements: One from you and one from the other stackoverflow-article with at least found two people correct. So I put both statements into it. So it neutral. More than to say I don't know it, I can't do.

Comment: Once last attempt to explain this, it's really very simple: the answer in that other thread *does not say* that SmartGWT cannot integrate with Play, cannot integrate with RestyGWT, or anything of the kind.  It says that SmartGWT requires SmartClient.  This is not a problem for integration with Play or with RestyGWT.  If you don't understand any of this, and you don't care to research further to find out that you are incorrect, then we'll just have to hope that StackOverflow does its job and this bit of misinformation is voted down into oblivion :)