# Gwt 2.1 with Smartgwt 3.0

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Hello i want to know if it´s possible work with GWT 2.1 version and smartgwt 3.0, coz i want implement a grid that just is available  with smartgwt 3.0 and the web site of my work have GWT 2.1, thanks a lot. Regards.

Comment: u rigth sorry... this laptop hehe

Answer (score 1):

SmartGWT is a full framework to "replace" GWT. What I mean is that you'll have problems using a single widget from smartgwt in a gwt app.

If you want to use SmartGWT, you should use it as your framework. See more info here: [SmartGWT with GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915374/smartgwt-with-gwt)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.  After re-reading my answer, I realized it was totally unclear !!

Comment: thanks... the thing is that i want use Grid Header Summaries grid :( but all the web site was made with simple GWT, thanks 4 u answer...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, that's what I'm using.
You could even use an older version of GWT I guess even if it is not recommended.
What is not recommended at all is using smartGWT components and GWT along side.  Either use only GWT or only smartGWT

Answer (score 0):

i'm using GWT 2.4 and have some components in gwtext, but now i m replacing those gwtext components by SmartGwt and its working fine.

you can use some components of smartgwt and some of GWT or any other library

just make sure the return type.. all d best.